Bind9 zone not loading: file not found
My Bind9 zone fails to load with these 2 errors:
    zone example.com/IN: loading from master file etc/bind/zones/db.example.com failed: file 
    not found
    zone example.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.

Here is named.conf.local
    zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "etc/bind/zones/db.example.com"; # zone file path
    allow-transfer { 10.0.0.0/8; };
};

and zone file
    ; base zone file for example.com
$TTL 2d    ; default TTL for zone
$ORIGIN example.com. ; base domain-name
; Start of Authority RR defining the key characteristics of the zone (domain)
@         IN      SOA   ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                                2003080800 ; serial number
                                12h        ; refresh
                                15m        ; update retry
                                3w         ; expiry
                                2h         ; minimum
                                )
; name server RR for the domain
           IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
; the second name server is external to this zone (domain)
           IN      NS      ns2.example.net.
; mail server RRs for the zone (domain)
        3w IN      MX  10  mail.example.com.
; the second  mail servers is  external to the zone (domain)
           IN      MX  20  mail.example.net.
; domain hosts includes NS and MX records defined above
; plus any others required
; for instance a user query for the A RR of joe.example.com will
; return the IPv4 address 192.168.254.6 from this zone file
ns1        IN      A       10.12.0.14
mail       IN      A       192.168.254.4
joe        IN      A       192.168.254.6
www        IN      A       192.168.254.7
; aliases ftp (ftp server) to an external domain
ftp        IN      CNAME   ftp.example.net.


Leading slash missing from the path? (/etc)

Thanks, @SmallClanger!  That was it!  You rock!
